# Sorting columns with CGridView in Yii based on function call in value

Tags: php, yii, cgridview

I have these codes in my view file:

```
    <?php $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'dataProvider'=>$dataProvider,
    'columns'=>array(
        array(
            'name' => 'Name',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::link(CHtml::encode($data->profile->first_name." ".$data->profile->last_name),array("match/view","id"=>$data->id))',
        ),
        array(
            'name' => 'Similiarity Score',
            'type'=>'raw',
            'value' => array($this, 'calculateScore'),
        ),
    ),
)); ?>
```

You will notice that the second column call the function calculateScore($data, $row) in the controller file. Is there anyway I can sort the table based on these scores?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that your result is from a database and you use a `CActiveDataProvider` or `CSqlDataProvider`. In this case you will have to move the logic for `calculateScore` into the DB query somehow. You can add a public property `score` to your model class and add this to the `select` property of your `CDbCriteria`:

```
$criteria->select = array('*', '... SQL FOR SCORE CALC HERE ... AS score');
```

Then you will be able to sort by that `score` in the `sort` definition of your `CActiveDataProvider`:

```
'sort' => array(
    'attributes' => array(
        // ...
        'score',
```

Comment: The logic of the calculateScore is a bit complex, basically each data row represent a User object and I would like to calculate its similarity index with the current User. Thus, it involves few tables join, looping through all users in the database and involve some complex prediction algorithm. In short, it is too complicated to be achieved via SQL query (might be possible, but prefer not to). Any thoughts?

Comment: Then you're out of luck. Sorting is job of the Database because you probably don't want to load all rows from DB and sort on PHP side - unless you talk about a very low number of rows in total. And as you need the score for sorting you need to find a way how you can move it's calculation to the DB. Maybe denormalize the score and store it to the DB as a separate column.